# Default Dispatchers use shared threadpool in Coroutines?

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

After reading the doc on Default Dispatcher -
https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-default.html

It says,

> It is backed by a **shared** pool of threads on JVM and Native.

I have few questions here -
Is the threadpool shared between Dispatchers in the current process? Or is this threadpool shared across processes? In other words, does each app has its own threadpool which consists of threads that are shared between dispatchers? If so, then when or how is this threadpool created? does it happen lazily when coroutine is launched?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**very good question**

- each process has it's own threads and thread bool of any process dosnt resalted to another process so  Dispatchers sharing threadpool in the current process
- thread bool initialized when the coroutine library is initialized and associated with `Dispatchers.Default`
- thread bool initialized eagerly not lazy during the initialization of the coroutine framework

there is a good book related to coroutine and asynchronous programming very good [Kotlin Coroutine with tutorial](https://pdfcoffee.com/kotlin-coroutines-by-tutorials-pdf-free.html) i advice you to read it

Comment: Thanks @m0haMed for your answer and tutorial link. Will definitely check it out!